# Modifying previous_posts link to use AJAX

Tags: pagination

I am editing the `wp-includes/link-template.php` file in Wordpress, and would like to use Ajax to load posts into my ID of `#box-right`. I am aware that there are many plugins for this usage but I am using my own HTML and CSS layout, and including posts (not having integrated my site with WordPress).

I am using AJAX to load content in certain DIV's within my site, I need to change the following code to load posts into my box-right div.

```
return '<a href="' . previous_posts( false ) . "\" $attr>". preg_replace( '/&([^#])(?![a-z]{1,8};)/i', '&#038;$1', $label ) .'</a>';
```

The AJAX link looks like this:

```
<a href="#" "onclick="javascript:ajax_loadContent('box-right','page-here.php');return false">
```

I need to make the top link load the AJAX, I thought it would look like this (I am new to PHP).

```
return '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ajax_loadContent(\'box-right\','. previous_posts( false ) . "\"');return false>$attr>". preg_replace( '/&([^#])(?![a-z]{1,8};)/i', '&#038;$1', $label ) .'</a>';
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here?" --> Editing the core.

Comment: Jack, do you really think that _"Noob question - PHP link help!"_ is a proper description for your question?

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong here?

First, and foremost...

> I am editing the wp-includes/link-template.php file in Wordpress

**Don't hack Core files!** Especially when there is a filter that should do what you need.

```
add_filter(
  'previous_posts_link_attributes',
  function ($clauses) {
    echo 'previous_posts_link_attributes';
    return 'test="attribute"';
  },
  1
);
```

You could insert your `onclick` with the filter.

However, your Javascript should be able to hijack the link without *any* manipulation of the markup at all (without that hackish `onclick`), which would be the proper way to do this.

Comment: Thanks again, I have added `add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_attributes_1');
add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_attributes_2');

function posts_link_attributes_1() {
    return 'class="prev_button" onclick="javascript:ajax_loadContent(\'box-right\',' . next_posts_link() . '");return false"';
}

function posts_link_attributes_2() {
    return 'class="next_button" onclick="javascript:ajax_loadContent(\'box-right\',' . previous_posts_link() . '");return false"';
}` which loads the class, but how do I make the ` . previous_posts_link() . ` actually work?